# How to perform a Post hoc test on anova

Tags: r, anova, tukey

How do I perform a post hoc test for `anova` and not the `aov` command. For example:

```
anova(cap.res,
 by = "terms",
 step = 1000)
```

I want a post hoc comparison after I get the `anova` results. I have a three-way comparison, "N", "C", and "S".

Answer (score 0):

This was posted ages ago, but just for clarification in case anybody discovers this, `anova` and `aov` have similar names but incomparable functions. Looking at the help page, you can see that the `anova` function is actually used for comparing models via tables, whereas the `aov` function is used for classical ANOVA tests only. As an example:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(rstatix)

#### Fit LR, AOV, and ANOVA ####
fit <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species,
          data=iris)
fit2 <- anova(fit)
fit3 <- aov(fit)

#### Run Tukeys ####
tukey_hsd(fit)
tukey_hsd(fit2)
tukey_hsd(fit3)
```

If you run `fit` and `fit3`, you will basically get the same Tukey PWC's:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
  term   group1 group2 null.…¹ estim…² conf.…³ conf.…⁴    p.adj p.adj…⁵
* <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
1 Speci… setosa versi…       0  -0.658 -0.819   -0.497 3.1 e-14 ****   
2 Speci… setosa virgi…       0  -0.454 -0.615   -0.293 1.36e- 9 ****   
3 Speci… versi… virgi…       0   0.204  0.0431   0.365 8.78e- 3 **     
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​null.value, ²​estimate, ³​conf.low,
#   ⁴​conf.high, ⁵​p.adj.signif
```

This is because in many ways the linear regression and anova here are mostly functionally equivalent. However, you get an error when doing the same with `fit2`:

```
Error in tukey_hsd.data.frame(fit2) : 
  argument "formula" is missing, with no default
```

The formula it is looking for here is `aov` or `lm` class if you look in the help page:

```
Arguments
x   
an object of class aov, lm or data.frame containing the variables used in the formula.
```